# C execvp won't execute the "ls -l" command but will execute "ls"

Tags: c

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int flag;
void catch (int sig)
{

  if (sig == SIGINT){
  flag = 1;
  }

  if (sig == SIGHUP){
  flag == 2;
  }
}



int main ()
{
  int i;
  char *nargs[40];
  nargs[0] = "ls-l";
  signal(SIGINT, catch);
  signal(SIGHUP, catch);
  i = 2;
  while(i == 2){
   if (flag == 1){
        execvp(nargs[0],nargs);
   }
   if (flag ==2){
        execvp(nargs[1],nargs);
   }

 }
  return 0;
}
```

Here when nargs[0] is set to "ls-l" or "ls -l" it will not execute the command on SIGINT, but when nargs[0] is set to "ls" it will execute the command just fine. What am I doing wrong? The while loop condition is only the way that it is so that it will loop forever.

Comment: The arguments separated by spaces on the command line must be separate strings in C.

Comment: “ls-l” wouldn’t even work from a shell in a standard environment..

Comment: This code is doing a busy-wait, which means it keeps one CPU core busy 100% just waiting for a signal. Use the `pause()` function to sleep until a signal is received. Also, signal handling is hard to do without running into race conditions. It is much safer to use the "self-pipe" trick: use `pipe()` to create a pipe, and in your `catch()` function just write the signal number to one end of the pipe. In `main()`, use a blocking read on the other end of the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execvp()` does not start a shell, it tries to find the binary you specify directly in the `$PATH`. So if you created an alias `ls-l` in your shell's startup scripts, then this won't work with `execvp()`. If you want that, use `system()` instead.

If you intended to execute `ls -l`, then you should do something like this:

```
const char *nargs[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
execvp(nargs[0], nargs);
```

Finally, if you really want to get a list of files, you don't need to call `ls`, you should use `opendir()`+`readdir()`, or alternatively `ftw()` on POSIX platforms.

Comment: Thank you that seemed to work! If I wanted to have other commands available for other signals, how would I do this?

Comment: @Coder567: then you create multiple arrays of arguments, like `const char *nargs1[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL}; const char *nargs2 = {"echo", "hello", NULL};`, and then call either `execve(nargs1[0], nargs1)` or `execve(nargs2[0], nargs2)` depending on which signal you received.